# Visual Studio 2012 Express incorrect behavior of text cutting

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Let me explain what I mean.

Example:

1) I am cutting some text on `line 1` (or some count of lines)

2) I am deleting empty `line 1`, that remained after text cutting

3) I am trying to paste cutted text to other place, but all what I get is an `empty string!` WTF (Why this Fhappens)??

If I`ll do **3rd step before 2nd**, I`ll get normal text pasting. But most of time I need to do 2nd step before 3rd.

Some of my coworkers get this bug too on Visual Studio Proffessional.

May be you had seen this bug too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you deleting the empty line?  If you're using CTRL-X or CTRL-Del, both of these commands will actually do a Cut command on the line.

Comment: CTRL + L, Hmm, If delete line using backspace, paste will be normal. But delete by backspace is not so fast. I`ll update question

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know, that `CTRL + L` cutting line, I thought that that it should delete line. This is my fault. Here is documentation for `CTRL + L` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2005/04/08/did-you-know-ctrl-l-cuts-the-current-line-and-ctrl-w-selects-the-current-word.aspx